# How to extract a parameter from a list of functions in a loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop, statistics, extract

I have a large data set and I want to perform several functions at once and extract for each a parameter.

The test dataset:

```
testdf <- data.frame(vy = rnorm(60), vx = rnorm(60) , gvar = rep(c("a","b"), each=30))
```

I first definded a list of functions:

```
require(fBasics)
normfuns <- list(jarqueberaTest=jarqueberaTest, shapiroTest=shapiroTest, lillieTest=lillieTest)
```

Then a function to perform the tests by the grouping variable

```
mynormtest <- function(d) {
  norm_test <- res_reg <- list()
  for (i in c("a","b")){
    res_reg[[i]] <- residuals(lm(vy~vx, data=d[d$gvar==i,]))
    norm_test[[i]] <- lapply(normfuns, function(f) f(res_reg[[i]]))  
  }
  return(norm_test) 
}

mynormtest(testdf)
```

I obtain a list of test summaries for each grouping variable.
However, I am interested in getting only the parameter "STATISTIC" and I did not manage to find out how to extract it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the value stored as "STATISTIC" in the output of the various tests with

```
res_list <- mynormtest(testdf)
res_list$a$shapiroTest@test@statistic
res_list$a$jarqueberaTest@test@statistic
res_list$a$lillieTest@test@statistic
```

And correspondingly for set b:

```
res_list$b$shapiroTest@test$statistic
res_list$b$jarqueberaTest@test$statistic
res_listb$lillieTest@test$statistic
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try to add this code within the for-loop, such as to get a table with group x statistic. Any suggestion welcome

Comment: Speed is not the issue, but I have a large data set with many levels of the grouping variable and a few more tests to compute. Thus, getting a concise result with only the interesting parameters would be nice. I tried to improve with a second function (see my answer below), now I would like to combine both, possibly using lapply.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning your function `fgetparam` I think that it is a nice starting point. Here's my suggestion with a few minor modifications:

```
getparams2 <- function(myp) {
  m <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(myp), ncol=3)
  for (i in (1:length(myp))){
    m[i,] <- sapply(1:3,function(x) myp[[i]][[x]]@test$statistic)}
  return(m)
}
```

This function represents a minor generalization in the sense that it allows for an arbitrary number of observations, while in your case this was fixed to two cases, a and b. The code can certainly be further shortened, but it might then also become somewhat more cryptic. I believe that in developing a code it is helpful to preserve a certain compromise between efficacy and compactness on one hand and readability or easiness to understand on the other.

## Edit

As [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31213349/looking-for-a-more-elegant-way-to-populate-a-matrix-with-specific-values-from-a) by @akrun and @Roland the function `getparams2()` can be written in a much more elegant and shorter form. One possibility is

```
getparams2 <- function(myp) {
    matrix(unname(rapply(myp, function(x) x@test$statistic)),ncol=3)}
```

Another great alternative is

```
getparams2 <- function(myp){t(sapply(myp, sapply, function(x) x@test$statistic))}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for this useful generalization.