# Looking for a more elegant way to populate a matrix with specific values from a list

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a list with a rather complex structure from which I want to extract only a few specific values. Since the `dput` output of the data and the structure of the list seems to be problematic in this case, I reproduce here the code [posted yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178704/how-to-extract-a-parameter-from-a-list-of-functions-in-a-loop/31187360#31187360) by @user34771 that was used to generate this list:

```
set.seed(123)
testdf <- data.frame(vy = rnorm(60), vx = rnorm(60) , gvar = rep(c("a","b"), each=30))
require(fBasics)
normfuns <- list(jarqueberaTest=jarqueberaTest, shapiroTest=shapiroTest, lillieTest=lillieTest)
mynormtest <- function(d) {
norm_test <- res_reg <- list()
for (i in c("a","b")){
  res_reg[[i]] <- residuals(lm(vy~vx, data=d[d$gvar==i,]))
  norm_test[[i]] <- lapply(normfuns, function(f) f(res_reg[[i]]))  
 }
return(norm_test) 
}
res_list <- mynormtest(testdf)
```

For the data in `res_list`, I have a function that extracts the values that I'm interested in and stores them in a matrix:

```
getparams2 <- function(myp) {
m <- matrix(NA, nrow=length(myp), ncol=3)
for (i in (1:length(myp))){
 m[i,] <- sapply(1:3,function(x) myp[[i]][[x]]@test$statistic)}
return(m)
}
```

This function provides the desired output.

```
> getparams2(res_list)
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.9917054 0.9670860 0.08837058
[2,] 0.1421776 0.9806379 0.12619274
```

However, I'm not happy with the style of the function `getparams2()`with its `FOR` loop. I'd be glad to know if this function can be written in a more elegant and more compact form. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I edited the post. Hope it is reproducible now.

Comment: Perhaps `unname(rapply(res_list, function(x) x@test$statistic))`

Comment: Thanks, I think Roland's function matches more with your expected one.  I didn't pay much attention about the matrix output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a matrix:

```
t(sapply(res_list, sapply, function(x) x@test$statistic))
#  jarqueberaTest.X-squared shapiroTest.W lillieTest.D
#a                0.9917054     0.9670860   0.08837058
#b                0.1421776     0.9806379   0.12619274
```

Or with `rapply`:

```
t(simplify2array(rapply(res_list, function(x) x@test$statistic, how = "list")))
#  jarqueberaTest shapiroTest lillieTest
#a 0.9917054      0.967086    0.08837058
#b 0.1421776      0.9806379   0.1261927
```